# Password Validation with special characters

Tags: javascript, html

This is all I could write I need to check whether there is a special character in the password or not but for some reason it does not work what do I need to change so it can Validate if there are special characters or not. Do I need to add a separate function for the special characters or it can be added to the code I already have, all of the other check out is there a trick to it? Any suggestion ideas?

```
    <form>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="psw" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    </form>
    
    <div id="message">
     <ul>
     <li id="letter" class="invalid">One lowercase character</li>
     <li id="capital" class="invalid">One uppercase character</li>
     <li id="number" class="invalid">One number</li>
     <li id="character" class="invalid">One special character</li>
     <li id="length" class="invalid">Eight characters minimun</li>
     </ul>
    </div>


    var myInput = document.getElementById("psw");
    var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
    var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
    var number = document.getElementById("number");
    var length = document.getElementById("length");
    var character = document.getElementById("character");

    // When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
    myInput.onfocus = function() {
      document.getElementById("message").style.display = "inline-block";
    }
    
    // When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
    myInput.onblur = function() {
      document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
    }
    
    // When the user starts to type something inside the password field
    myInput.onkeyup = function() {
      // Validate lowercase letters
      var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
      if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
        letter.classList.remove("invalid");
        letter.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        letter.classList.remove("valid");
        letter.classList.add("invalid");
      }
      
      //Validate Special character This part does not i dont know what to do
      var character = /[!-*]/g;
      if(myInput.value.match(character)) {  
        characte.classList.remove("invalid");
        characte.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        characte.classList.remove("valid");
        characte.classList.add("invalid");
      }

      // Validate capital letters
      var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
      if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
        capital.classList.remove("invalid");
        capital.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        capital.classList.remove("valid");
        capital.classList.add("invalid");
      }
    
    
      // Validate numbers
      var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
      if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
        number.classList.remove("invalid");
        number.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        number.classList.remove("valid");
        number.classList.add("invalid");
      }
      
      // Validate length
      if(myInput.value.length >= 8) {
        length.classList.remove("invalid");
        length.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        length.classList.remove("valid");
        length.classList.add("invalid");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are wrong with your code which is why it is not working properly.

Please check your variables and objects. You are calling upon `characte` which is not declared anywhere.

You have declared the variable `character` twice. This will cause conflict. Make one of them unique to the other.

Pay attention to your console logs, there is usually always a clue there.

When I fix your typos and separate your `character` variable, it works;

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("psw");
    var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
    var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
    var number = document.getElementById("number");
    var length = document.getElementById("length");
    var character = document.getElementById("character");

    // When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
    myInput.onfocus = function() {
      document.getElementById("message").style.display = "inline-block";
    }
    
    // When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
    myInput.onblur = function() {
      document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
    }
    
    // When the user starts to type something inside the password field
    myInput.onkeyup = function() {
      // Validate lowercase letters
      var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
      if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
        letter.classList.remove("invalid");
        letter.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        letter.classList.remove("valid");
        letter.classList.add("invalid");
      }
      
      //Validate Special character This part does not i dont know what to do
      var specCharacter = /[!-*]/g;
      if(myInput.value.match(specCharacter)) {  
        character.classList.remove("invalid");
        character.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        character.classList.remove("valid");
        character.classList.add("invalid");
      }

      // Validate capital letters
      var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
      if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
        capital.classList.remove("invalid");
        capital.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        capital.classList.remove("valid");
        capital.classList.add("invalid");
      }
    
    
      // Validate numbers
      var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
      if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
        number.classList.remove("invalid");
        number.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        number.classList.remove("valid");
        number.classList.add("invalid");
      }
      
      // Validate length
      if(myInput.value.length >= 8) {
        length.classList.remove("invalid");
        length.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        length.classList.remove("valid");
        length.classList.add("invalid");
      }
    }
```

```html
    <form>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="psw" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    </form>
    
    <div id="message">
     <ul>
     <li id="letter" class="invalid">One lowercase character</li>
     <li id="capital" class="invalid">One uppercase character</li>
     <li id="number" class="invalid">One number</li>
     <li id="character" class="invalid">One special character</li>
     <li id="length" class="invalid">Eight characters minimun</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Your regex is also only looking for special characters between `!` and `*` if you want to expand this or are missing some let me know and I can tweak it or steer you in the right direction!

Comment: Thank you so much I do want to expand the special characters I want them to be [!@#$%&*]. Next time I will pay more attention thank you again.

Comment: @Backobaki - just change ``/[!-*]/g`` to be ``/[!@#$%^&*]/g``